# Is there a maximum limit time for functions in android alarm manager?

Tags: android, flutter, alarmmanager

I have an app that runs entirely local/offline, and at midnight (using [android_alarm_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus) and [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)) it does some processing to create and schedule user notifications based on the actual local data of the user and recreate the alarm at midnight, the problem is that after a few days these background processes just stop, if I put it to run every minute it works great when I'm using the device, but when running at midnight its only works on the first days, I even put some logs to see if any errors happened (creating logs in cache and reading them later), but after a few days the app just stops logging too. I think this is caused by android killing the services when it is taking a bit long, but I don't really sure, and if it is, there is another way to make background services on android or the best way is to put my app and user data online and with firebase create and send notifications?

Comment: Do you open your app in the meantime? If user doesn't interact with your app it will get knocked down into lower [priority bucket](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/appstandby) and it won't be able to run jobs and alarms.

Comment: @Pawel hmmm it is possible, because in my tests I was not entering the app, just to see if it will works, but in the other hand when I change this service to another one, really simpler and faster, it runs daily, even if I dont enter the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem, to solve this I used the same packages and the [Workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager), so with AlarmManager I can schedule a alarm to start at midnight that generates and start a periodic work (24 hours) to based on the user data send notifications to the user.
I think this one is a better approach because even [android says](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager#reliable) that WorkManager is the right tool to do background work and alarmmanager is for alarms only.